# Displaying a Java program using Processing for animation on the web

Tags: java, web, jar, processing, libraries

I have a set of .java files that use imported Processing classes (processing.core.PApplet & processing.core.PVector) to display graphics, and I need to display this through a web interface. It has some library dependencies when I run it on the desktop, such as the core.jar  and gluegen-rt.jar from Processing. Is there any simple way to do this (for example, would it run using Processing.js somehow? Or even as an embedded .jar?)? Or would I be better of converting to all-java or all-processing?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using a [Java Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)?

Comment: Currently the application is written as a PApplet, so I'm not sure if I can use a Java Applet...

Comment: Can you post an example of the PApplet you have ? If the animation isn't to complex, perhaps it could be rendered with Processing.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same question and found this [quick overview](http://www.sebastianoliva.com/en/en/2010/05/using-a-processing-sketch-as-a-java-component/trackback/index.html) on running Processing as a component in Java really helpful. Essentially, it is exactly as [Ruben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16861466/2441384) says about extending the PApplet class, the examples make it really clear.

Answer (score 0):

The [PApplet class](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html) extends the `java.applet.Applet` class, which is all you need to be able to display the Java application in a browser.

Follow the [Java Applet Getting Started Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html) to learn how to do this.

Just remember that some things that work in a client-side application may not be supported by Applets because the JAR runs in a sandbox. Here is a [list of things Applets can and cannot do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) in this sandbox.